# What is the fastest way to XOR A LOT of binary arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, hamming-distance

I am tasked with calculating hamming distances between 1D binary arrays in two groups - a group of 3000 arrays and a group of 10000 arrays, and every array is 100 items(bits) long. So thats 3000x10000 HD calculations on 100 bit long objects.And all that must be done in at most a dozen minutes

Here's the best of what I came up with

```
#X - 3000 by 100 bool np.array 
#Y - 10000 by 100 bool np.array
hd = []
i=1
for x in X:
    print("object nr " + str(i) + "/" + str(len(X)))
    arr = np.array([x] * len(Y)) 
    C = Y^arr # just xor this array by all the arrays in the other group simultainously
    hd.append([sum(c) for c in C]) #add up all the bits to get the hamming distance
    i+=1

return np.array(hd)
```

And it's still going to take 1-1.5 hours for it to finish. How do I go about making this faster?

Comment: Do you _have to_ use Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to dramatically improve the summing speed by using `numpy` to perform it, rather than using a list comprehension and the built-in `sum` function (that takes no advantage of `numpy` vectorized operations).

Just replace:

```
hd.append([sum(c) for c in C])
```

with:

```
# Explicitly use uint16 to reduce memory cost; if array sizes might increase
# you can use uint32 to leave some wiggle room
hd.append(C.sum(1, dtype=np.uint16))
```

which, for a 2D array, will return a new 1D array where each value is the sum of the corresponding row (thanks to specifying it should operate on `axis` `1`). For example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[True,False,True], [False,False,True], [True, True,True]], dtype=np.bool)
>>> arr.sum(1, np.uint16)
array([ 2, 1, 3], dtype=uint16)
```

Since it performs all the work at the C layer in a single operation without type conversions (instead of your original approach that requires a Python level loop that operates on each row, then an implicit loop that, while at the C layer, must still implicitly convert each `numpy` value one by one from `np.bool` to Python level `int`s just to sum them), this should run substantially faster for the array scales you're describing.

Side-note: While not the source of your performance problems, there is no reason to manually maintain your index value; [`enumerate` can do that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) more quickly and easily. Simply replace:

```
i=1
for x in X:
    ... rest of loop ...
    i+=1
```

with:

```
for i, x in enumerate(X, 1):
    ... rest of loop ...
```

and you'll get the same behavior, but slightly faster, more concise and cleaner in general.

Comment: Performance-wise, on an input array of 100 rows of 10000 elements each, `[sum(c) for c in C)]` took about 2 seconds to run on my machine; `C.sum(1, dtype=np.uint16)` took 737 µs, or about 0.037% of the original runtime (so 1-1.5 hours would reasonably be expected to drop to the 1-2 second range on this change alone). For 10000 rows of 100 elements each, the timings are longer, but still similar; the listcomp+`sum` solution took 2.11 seconds, the `numpy` solution took 914 µs. Either way, it should dramatically reduce runtime.

Comment: Holy Guacamole, you Sir are a genius! It runs so fast I honestly didn't think it was even possible!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`np.logical_xor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_xor.html) and list comprehension:

```
result = np.array([[np.logical_xor(X[a], Y[b].T).sum() for b in range(len(Y))] 
                                                       for a in range(len(X))])
```

The whole operation runs in 7 seconds in my machine.

```
0:00:07.226645
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are not limited to using Python, this is a solution in C++ using `bitset`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

using real = double;

std::mt19937_64 rng;
std::uniform_real_distribution<real> bitset_dist(0, 1);
real prob(0.75);

std::bitset<100> rand_bitset()
{
    std::bitset<100> bitset;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < bitset.size(); ++idx)
    {
         bitset[idx] = (bitset_dist(rng) < prob) ? true : false;
    }
    return std::move(bitset);
}

int main()
{
    rng.seed(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

    size_t v1_size(3000);
    size_t v2_size(10000);

    std::vector<size_t> hd;
    std::vector<std::bitset<100>> vec1;
    std::vector<std::bitset<100>> vec2;
    vec1.reserve(v1_size);
    vec2.reserve(v2_size);
    hd.reserve(v1_size * v2_size); /// Edited from hd.reserve(v1_size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v1_size; ++i)
    {
        vec1.emplace_back(rand_bitset());
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v2_size; ++i)
    {
        vec2.emplace_back(rand_bitset());
    }

    std::cout << "vec1 size: " << vec1.size() << '\n'
              << "vec2 size: " << vec2.size() << '\n';

    auto start(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
    for (const auto& b1 : vec1)
    {
        for (const auto& b2 : vec2)
        {
            /// Count only the bits that are set and store them
            hd.emplace_back((b1 ^ b2).count());
        }
    }
    auto time(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count());

    std::cout << vec1.size() << " x " << vec2.size()
              << " xor operations on 100 bits took " << time << " ms\n";
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, the whole operation (`3000` x `10000`) takes about `300` ms.

You could put this into a function, compile it into a library and call it from Python. Another option is to store the distances to a file and then read them in Python.

---

EDIT: I had the wrong size for the hd vector. Reserving the proper amount of memory reduces the operation to about `190` ms because relocations are avoided.